# How do I write a conditional redirect into a model's create method, in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I'm allowing users to create a 'Question' from different pages in the app, and want them to be redirected to the right page after the new question is saved. Since one page has a params[:id] and one doesn't, I thought I'd use that to differentiate between the different redirects.

Here's what I was trying to do in my Questions controller:

```
respond_to do |format|  
if @question.save
    if params[:id].nil?
      format.html {redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => 'show', :username => question.directed_to}  
    else
      format.html {redirect_to :controller => 'mentions', :action => 'show', :id => question.topic}
    end    
else
    ...
end
```

Thanks very much, I'm still new to this.

Comment: What results are you getting? I take it that it's not working, but are you getting errors? Is it always going to the same page? Little more detail is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on params beings nil is super awkward. You have control of the forms being submitted, so just sent an extra parameter yourself which identifies where it's coming from.

A few other things:

If you're only responding with html, don't bother doing the respond_to block.

```
if @question.save
  redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => 'show', :username => question.directed_to
else
  redirect_to :controller => 'mentions', :action => 'show', :id => question.topic
end
```

`@question.save` doesn't run validations. It's pretty unusual that you'd want to have a create action that doesn't run validations. You should probably having something like:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @question.save!
  flash[:notice] = "Question saved successfully"
  # Do your redirects here
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  flash[:error] = "There were errors saving your question"
  render :action => :new
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'send (set?) an extra parameter to identify where it's coming from'? I could run a migration to add an extra attribute to the Questions model (like :type_of_question), and then set the value of that attribute in the form, but is that really necessary?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an attribute of the Questions model. You could do something like `hidden_field_tag 'source', 'page1'` which you can access with `params[:source]`. Since this isn't passed as part of `params[:question]`, it doesn't need an `attr_accesor` on the Questions model.

Comment: @kateray Awesome. If you don't have any more questions and everything is working correctly, please accept the answer.

Comment: Hmm, one issue: I can't say 'render :action => :new' when there are errors because I need to redirect back to the same places I do when the question saves correctly. However, calling a 'redirect' rather than a 'render' seems to make me lose all my custom error messages (like what happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638215/rails-does-not-display-error-messages-on-a-form-in-a-custom-method).
I know that's a slightly different question....